# SVG clipPath with USE breaking in Safari when updating linked shape

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, safari, webkit

I have an SVG that looks something like:

```html
<svg ...>
  <rect id="clipShape" width="500" height="500"></rect>

  <g id="content" clip-path="url(#clip)">
    <!-- some content -->
  </g>

  <clipPath id="clip">
    <use xlink:href="#clipShape"></use>
  </clipPath>
</svg>
```

I need to make adjustments to `#clipSource`, e.g. changing `width` and `height`, over the lifecycle of the SVG. However doing e.g.:

```javascript
d3.select('#clipShape').attr({ height: "200", width: "200" });
```

will break clipping in Safari. The `#content` will be hidden altogether, as if `clipPath` is invalid. I can force similar behavior by not setting the `use` `href` under the `xlink` namespace.

I've captured the issue in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joenudell/6ftozo9r/4/). I don't see this issue in Chrome, FF, Opera, or IE11.

Questions:

1. Am I being uncouth modifying the linked shape?
2. If couth, is this a known bug in Safari/WebKit?
3. Any thoughts about a workaround?

Comment: Your jsFiddle works correctly on my Mac, in Safari 6.1.6 (7537.78.2)

Comment: Thanks! It fails for me on my MBP on Safari 8.0.3 (10600.3.18)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this is a bug in WebKit, the fiddle fails in the latest nightly (r180500). I've [reported the bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141929).

To work around the issue, I'm cloning `#clipShape` into the `clipPath` - repeating this operation as necessary when I need to change any attributes of `#clipShape`.